# How do I make vim indent java annotations correctly?

Tags: java, vim, annotations

When indenting java code with annotations, vim insists on indenting like this:

```
@Test
    public void ...
```

I want the annotation to be in the same column as the method definition but I can't seem to find a way to tell vim to do that, except maybe using an indent expression but I'm not sure if I can use that together with regular cindent.

edit: The filetype plugin was already turned on I just got a bit confused about indenting plugins. The accepted answer may be a bit hackish but works for me as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: I cannot delete my own answer because it has already been accepted, but [@pydave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414015/2844) seems to be the better (more robust) solution.

---

You should probably be using the indentation file for the java FileType (instead of using cindent) by setting `filetype plugin indent on`.

That said, the indentation file coming with the Vim 7.1 from my linux distribution (looking at the current vim svn this is still true for 7.2) doesn't account for annotations yet. I therefore copied `/usr/share/vim/vim71/indent/java.vim` (see https://vim.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/vim/branches/vim7.1/runtime/indent/java.vim) to `~/.vim/indent/java.vim` and added the following lines right before the end:

```
let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
let line = getline(lnum)
if line =~ '^\s*@.*$'
    let theIndent = indent(lnum)
endif
```

I'm not sure if this breaks any of the other indentations, but it works for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me - I added it right at the end. I'm using vim 7.2
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: :facepalm: worked now - I was adding it at the very end and not at the end of the function :D

Thanks !

Comment: Worked fine for me too. I also changed the cinoptions line at the beginning to this: cinoptions+=(s,m1,M0,j1

Answer (score 18):

You shouldn't modify the built-in vim settings. Your changes could disappear after a package upgrade. If you copy it to your .vim, then you won't get any java indent bug fixes.

Instead, put the following into a new file called `~/.vim/after/indent/java.vim`

```
function! GetJavaIndent_improved()
    let theIndent = GetJavaIndent()
    let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
    let line = getline(lnum)
    if line =~ '^\s*@.*$'
        let theIndent = indent(lnum)
    endif

    return theIndent
endfunction
setlocal indentexpr=GetJavaIndent_improved()
```

That way it loads the stock java indent and only modifies the indent to remove the annotation indents.

Answer (score 1):

I found pydave's suggestion *almost* what I wanted, but I wanted this:

```
@Override
public void ...
```

**and** this:

```
@Override public void ...
```

so I replaced the regex (as per pydave's, place in `~/.vim/after/indent/java.vim`):

```
setlocal indentexpr=GetJavaIndent_improved()

function! GetJavaIndent_improved()
    let theIndent = GetJavaIndent()
    let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
    let line = getline(lnum)
    if line =~ '^\s*@[^{]*$'
        let theIndent = indent(lnum)
    endif

    return theIndent
endfunction
```