# How do I correctly indent annotations in vim?

Tags: java, vim, annotations, indentation

I am having trouble getting vim to correctly indent text after java annotations (like `@Override` or `@Test`). I attempted to use the second answer from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200932/how-do-i-make-vim-indent-java-annotations-correctly). After I tried the solution found there it still isn't indenting incorrectly.

When both the java.vim file and my .vimrc are loaded nothing is different (I suspect that the smartindent defined in my .vimrc is taking precedence), and when I load vim with no .vimrc and :source ~/.vim/after/indent/java.vim manually it indents everything by removing all indentation (moving everything to the far left).

I'm running VIM 7.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.2. Any tips? Here is my .vim folder so you can double check the file: https://github.com/ElliotPenson/.vim Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked this question and I'm not sure if your settings have changed, but the github folder you included lacks the `after/indent/java.vim` file the other question you linked mentions. This would be the key to that answer working for you.