# How to remove indent after annotation in Java

Tags: vim, indentation

I have `@Override` annotation in my java code, but vim indent the next line automatically like this:

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
        //some code
    }
```

How can I get rid of the indent?

As far as I know, the indent file `java.vim` in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent` has addressed the problem, yet the problem still remains. Here's the code in `java.vim`:

```
  " If the previous line starts with '@', we should have the same indent as
  " the previous one
  if getline(lnum) =~ '^\s*@\S\+\s*$'
     return indent(lnum)
  endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make vim indent java annotations correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200932/how-do-i-make-vim-indent-java-annotations-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I just tested this on version 7.3.918 with both snippets and they both work. This means that something is wrong with your vim setup. Take a look at your vimrc and see if anything is wrong.

Also look at the value returned by `:set ft` it should return filetype=java. If this does not happen make sure you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc and check to see if this fixes your problem.

Also the below snippet does not to be used because vim does this by itself in later versions.

---

I have this in the file `~/.vim/after/indent/java.vim` which was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414015/1890567)

```
function! GetJavaIndent_improved()
    let theIndent = GetJavaIndent()
    let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
    let line = getline(lnum)
    if line =~ '^\s*@.*$'
        let theIndent = indent(lnum)
    endif

    return theIndent
endfunction
setlocal indentexpr=GetJavaIndent_improved()
```

This seems to work for indenting java annotations properly.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed can you try running vim with out any of the plugins

Comment: No, I currently have no pulgins installed.

Comment: What version of vim are you running?

Comment: @Stanley Did you see the edit I made to the post? Did that help?