# vim indent after java annotations

Tags: java, vim

Does anyone know how to make vim correctly indent after annotations? I've tried the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228548/how-to-remove-indent-after-annotation-in-java) to no avail. I've read that it was fixed in vim 7.3 and I've gone ahead and installed 7.4 but it doesn't appear fixed and it's really driving me insane.

I suspect it might have to do with the fact I'm on OS X.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on

set expandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal softtabstop=4

set ruler
syntax on
```

and here is java.vim

```
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal softtabstop=4

function! GetJavaIndent_improved()
    let theIndent = GetJavaIndent()
    let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
    let line = getline(lnum)
    if line =~ '^\s*@.*$'
        let theIndent = indent(lnum)
    endif

    return theIndent
endfunction
setlocal indentexpr=GetJavaIndent_improved()
```

Comment: Do you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc (Maybe post your vimrc)? What is the value of `set ft?` is it java? I just tested it in 7.4 patches 1-35 on Mac OS X and it still seems to work.

Comment: Lines 71-75 of `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/java.vim` should contain the fix the java annotations.

Comment: If you previously did something to fix this, then that might be overriding the updated indent function.  @FDinoff is right, and you should also check `verbose set ft? indentexpr?`:  I get

  filetype=java
 Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-65/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim
  indentexpr=GetJavaIndent()
 Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-65/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent/java.vim` -- I would be very surprised if your problem has anything to do with your OS.

Comment: @FDinoff :set ft returns filetype=java. Sorry can you show me how to view the java.vim at runtime?

Comment: Also, how did you guys install vim? I used brew to install it. Not sure if it would make a difference.

Comment: inside vim type `:e $VIMRUNTIME/indent/java.vim` to view the indent file. I installed it with vim. Are you sure you are using the correct version? Where is java.vim located (but it shouldn't be necessary)?

Comment: That should say installed with macports...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I realized what happened. One of my terminals was opened before I changed bashrc and so it was still on the old version. My bad guys! Thanks for all your help

Comment: @FDinoff Also thanks for showing me this trick. That's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me. Perhaps you could post a snippet of your code showing the incorrect indentation? My Java code gets indented like this:

```
class Indent {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm an indent";
    }

}
```

Be sure you have the line

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

somewhere in your vimrc. Java indentation will only work if the filetype has been properly recognised. Run `:set filetype?` in your Java file – Vim should answer `java`.